# PHP + MySQL transactions examples

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I really haven't found normal example of PHP file where MySQL transactions are being used. Can you show me simple example of that?

And one more question. I've already done a lot of programming and didn't use transactions. Can I put a PHP function or something in `header.php` that if one `mysql_query` fails, then the others fail too?

---

I think I have figured it out, is it right?:

```
mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

$a1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rarara (l_id) VALUES('1')");
$a2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rarara (l_id) VALUES('2')");

if ($a1 and $a2) {
    mysql_query("COMMIT");
} else {        
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}
```

Comment: You can use
`mysql_query("BEGIN");`
instead of sequence
`mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");`
`mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Kirzilla it didn't work for me. You need to call `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0` for BEGIN too.

Comment: Does "mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");" set all connections to wait for commit function or it's just for its related connection?

Comment: @Neal, Actually `mysql` wun die despite being deprecated, it will be available in PECL forever.

Comment: @Pacerier Things that get deprecated don't "die". They are held officially for legacy software but cease to be maintained and stricken from any recommended practices for new software. The fact remains, don't use `mysql`

Comment: @taylorcressy PHP website says it will die. "It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development, as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 **and will be removed in the future**." (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: @waste Fine, it will die. But that is not synonymous with being deprecated. Thus, my comment stands.

Answer (score 350, accepted):

The idea I generally use when working with transactions looks like this *(semi-pseudo-code)*:

```
try {
    // First of all, let's begin a transaction
    $db->beginTransaction();
    
    // A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
    $db->query('first query');
    $db->query('second query');
    $db->query('third query');
    
    // If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
    // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
    $db->commit();
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    // An exception has been thrown
    // We must rollback the transaction
    $db->rollback();
    throw $e; // but the error must be handled anyway
}
```

Note that, with this idea, if a query fails, an Exception must be thrown:

- PDO can do that, depending on how you configure it

  - See [`PDO::setAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)
  - and `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` and `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`
- else, with some other API, you might have to test the result of the function used to execute a query, and throw an exception yourself.

Unfortunately, there is no magic involved. You cannot just put an instruction somewhere and have transactions done automatically: you still have to specific which group of queries must be executed in a transaction.

For example, quite often you'll have a couple of queries before the transaction *(before the `begin`)* and another couple of queries after the transaction *(after either `commit` or `rollback`)* and you'll want those queries executed no matter what happened *(or not)* in the transaction.

Comment: Be careful if you are doing operations that may throw exceptions other than db ones. If so, an exception from a non-db statement may cause a rollback inadvertently (even if all the db calls are successful). Normally, you'd think rolling back is a good idea even if the error was not on the db side, but there are times 3rd party/non-critical code may cause not-so-important exceptions, and you still want to continue with the transaction.

Comment: What is the `$db` type here? mysqli?

Comment: @Jake See my answer for an example that uses mysqli (similar in style to Pascal's approach).

Comment: it can easily be modified to catch `PDOException` and even check exception values if needed. http://us2.php.net/PDOException

Comment: what happens if you omit the $db->rollback(); and an exception is thrown?

Comment: @Clox all hell breaks loose... the queries executed before the exception are done.

Comment: What about setting up the transaction code from within a stored procedure? Why is that frowned upon?

Comment: Can you just write it as a string and send it as one query? i.e.
$MySQL_string = "START TRANSACTION; ";
$MySQL_string .= "UPDATE MyGuests SET firstname = 'Dave', reg_date = NOW() WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1; ";
$MySQL_string .= "UPDATE MyGuests SET firstname = 'Sam', reg_date = NOW() WHERE id = 2 LIMIT 1; ";
$MySQL_string .= "COMMIT; "; $DB->mysqli->query($MySQL_string)

Comment: Also - is it ok to run your $db->query('first query'); etc in a for loop?

Comment: **$db** is the PDO object (connection). Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: To expand on @HalilÖzgür 's comment above, if you use **mysqli**, you might want to catch `mysqli_sql_exception` instead of simply `Throwable`. Or use separate `catch` blocks in case you have non-DB exceptions you might want to handle.

Answer (score 116):

I think I have figured it out, is it right?:

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

$a1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rarara (l_id) VALUES('1')");
$a2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rarara (l_id) VALUES('2')");

if ($a1 and $a2) {
    mysql_query("COMMIT");
} else {        
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}
```

Comment: Engine store should be InnoDB, not MyISAM!

Answer (score 42):

```
<?php

// trans.php
function begin(){
    mysql_query("BEGIN");
}

function commit(){
    mysql_query("COMMIT");
}

function rollback(){
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}

mysql_connect("localhost","Dude1", "SuperSecret") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("bedrock") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO employee (ssn,name,phone) values ('123-45-6789','Matt','1-800-555-1212')";

begin(); // transaction begins

$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!$result){
    rollback(); // transaction rolls back
    echo "transaction rolled back";
    exit;
}else{
    commit(); // transaction is committed
    echo "Database transaction was successful";
}

?>
```

Comment: For a broad and high profile question like this, it would be great if the answers also reflected that. Your code sample is great, but can you elaborate more? Explain about transactions, why, when and where? Finally, link the code with your explanation.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please always write some describing text to your answer.

Comment: sorry im begginer,  and my bad english, its very easy examle of code - for begginers -  commit() rollback() begin() put in class DB (for example),  $query - not once - maybe $query0 $query1 - then chek them - i use this code, this very easy to understand =)

Comment: His comments make the example pretty clear. Good code shouldn't need describing text. Also the question asks for a simple example. I like this answer.

Comment: @GedzbergAlex for a single query there is no need of transaction, simply it confuses about the transaction, Is there a reason to use the transaction for a single query?

Answer (score 41):

As this is the first result on google for "php mysql transaction", I thought I'd add an answer that explicitly demonstrates how to do this with mysqli (as the original author wanted examples). Here's a simplified example of transactions with PHP/mysqli:

> **Note:** this is meant for InnoDB tables. Won't work with MyISAM tables.

```
// let's pretend that a user wants to create a new "group". we will do so
// while at the same time creating a "membership" for the group which
// consists solely of the user themselves (at first). accordingly, the group
// and membership records should be created together, or not at all.
// this sounds like a job for: TRANSACTIONS! (*cue music*)

$group_name = "The Thursday Thumpers";
$member_name = "EleventyOne";

// tell mysqli to throw exception in case of error
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
// connect
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_passwd, $db_name);

try {

    $conn->begin_transaction();

    // assume that the TABLE groups has an auto_increment id field
    $query = "INSERT INTO groups (name) VALUES (?)";
    $conn->execute_query($query, [$group_name]);
    $group_id = $conn->insert_id; // last auto_inc id from *this* connection

    $query = "INSERT INTO group_membership (group_id,name) VALUES (?,?)";
    $conn->execute_query($query, [$group_id,$member_name]);

    // our SQL queries have been successful. commit them
    $conn->commit();
}
catch ( \Throwable $e ) {
    $conn->rollback(); 
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: On a related note, I just discovered that if you're working with InnoDB tables, it IS possible to lock/unlock tables when using the autocomitt() approach to transactions, but it is NOT possible when using the begin_transaction() approach: [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html)

Comment: +1 for detailed (and commented) example with actual mysqli code. Thanks for this. And your point about locking/transactions is very interesting indeed.

Comment: Does "autocommit(FALSE)" will affect to another connection in same database/table ? I mean if we open two pages that one of them set its connection to "autocommit(FALSE)" but other one left the autocommit function, does it wait for commit function or not. I want to know if autocommit is an attribute for connections and not for database/table. Thanks

Comment: @Hamid `$conn->autocommit(FALSE)`, in the example above, is only affecting the individual connection - it has no effect on any other connections to the database.

Comment: NOTE: instead of `if (!result)`, should do `if (result === false)`, if the query is capable of returning a valid result that would evaluate to false or zero.

Comment: @EleventyOne It seems to me that this solution is insecure because it could be vulnerable to SQL injection. What would I need to do to this to use it with prepared statements?

Answer (score 12):

Please check which storage engine you are using. If it is MyISAM, then `Transaction('COMMIT','ROLLBACK')` will not be supported because only the InnoDB storage engine, not MyISAM, supports transactions.

Answer (score 10):

When using PDO connection:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8', $user, $pass, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, // this is important
]);
```

I often use the following code for transaction management:

```
function transaction(Closure $callback)
{
    global $pdo; // let's assume our PDO connection is in a global var

    // start the transaction outside of the try block, because
    // you don't want to rollback a transaction that failed to start
    $pdo->beginTransaction(); 
    try
    {
        $callback();
        $pdo->commit(); 
    }
    catch (Exception $e) // it's better to replace this with Throwable on PHP 7+
    {
        $pdo->rollBack();
        throw $e; // we still have to complain about the exception
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
transaction(function()
{
    global $pdo;

    $pdo->query('first query');
    $pdo->query('second query');
    $pdo->query('third query');
});
```

This way the transaction-management code is not duplicated across the project. Which is a good thing, because, judging from other PDO-ralated answers in this thread, it's easy to make mistakes in it. The most common ones being forgetting to rethrow the exception and starting the transaction inside the `try` block.

Answer (score 5):

I made a function to get a vector of queries and do a transaction, maybe someone will find out it useful:

```
function transaction ($con, $Q){
        mysqli_query($con, "START TRANSACTION");

        for ($i = 0; $i < count ($Q); $i++){
            if (!mysqli_query ($con, $Q[$i])){
                echo 'Error! Info: <' . mysqli_error ($con) . '> Query: <' . $Q[$i] . '>';
                break;
            }   
        }

        if ($i == count ($Q)){
            mysqli_query($con, "COMMIT");
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            mysqli_query($con, "ROLLBACK");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this, but not sure if this is correct. Could try this out also.

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
$flag = true;
$query = "INSERT INTO testing (myid) VALUES ('test')";

$query2 = "INSERT INTO testing2 (myid2) VALUES ('test2')";

$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
if (!$result) {
$flag = false;
}

$result = mysql_query($query2) or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
if (!$result) {
$flag = false;
}

if ($flag) {
mysql_query("COMMIT");
} else {        
mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}
```

Idea from here: http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/transactions/

Comment: Not correct code.  trigger_error will return true (unless you've screwed up your call), so $result will always be true, so this code will miss any failed query, and always attempt to commit.  Equally troubling, you are using the old deprecated `mysql_query`, instead of using `mysqli`, even though you link to a tutorial that uses `mysqli`.  IMHO, you should either delete this bad example, or replace it to use code as written in the phpknowhow tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

One more procedural style example with `mysqli_multi_query`, assumes `$query` is filled with semicolon-separated statements.

```
mysqli_begin_transaction ($link);

for (mysqli_multi_query ($link, $query);
    mysqli_more_results ($link);
    mysqli_next_result ($link) );

! mysqli_errno ($link) ?
    mysqli_commit ($link) : mysqli_rollback ($link);
```

Comment: Somewhat strange code, but at least it suggests the use of `mysqli_multi_query`.  Anyone interested in that should google elsewhere for cleaner example.

Comment: `mysqli_multi_query()` is not advisable if there is any user-supplied data in the queries.  Prepared statements are not supported in this function.