# How do I use MySQL transactions in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I'm sorry, this is a very general question but I will try to narrow it down.

I'm new to this whole transaction thing in MySQL/PHP but it seems pretty simple. I'm just using mysql not mysqli or PDO. I have a script that seems to be rolling back some queries but not others. This is uncharted territory for me so I have no idea what is going on.

I start the transaction with `mysql_query('START TRANSACTION;')`, which I understand disables autocommit at the same time. Then I have a lot of complex code and whenever I do a query it is something like this `mysql_query($sql) or $error = "Oh noes!"`. Then periodically I have a function called `error_check()` which checks if `$error` is not empty and if it isn't I do `mysql_query('ROLLBACK;')` and `die($error)`. Later on in the code I have `mysql_query('COMMIT;')`. But if I do two queries and then purposely throw an error, I mean just set $error = something, it looks like the first query rolls back but the second one doesn't.

What could be going wrong? Are there some gotchas with transactions I don't know about? I don't have a good understanding of how these transactions start and stop especially when you mix PHP into it...

**EDIT:**
My example was overly simplified I actually have at least two transactions doing INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE on separate tables. But before I execute each of those statements I backup the rows in corresponding "history" tables to allow undoing. It looks like the manipulation of the main tables gets rolled back but entries in the history tables remain.

**EDIT2:**
Doh! As I finished typing the previous edit it dawned on me...there must be something wrong with those particular tables...for some reason they were all set as MyISAM.

Comment: Possible Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples

Comment: Yeah, that is somewhat related, unfortunately it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note to self: Make sure all the tables use transaction-supporting engines. Dummy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) functions rather than [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), as they offer some worthwhile improvements—especially the use of [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to determine where the problem lies.  Given that you say your code is complex, it is likely that the problem lies with your code rather than MySQL transactions.

Have you tried creating some standalone test scripts?  Perhaps you could isolate the SQL statements from your application, and create a simple script which simply runs them in series.  If that works, you have narrowed down the source of the problem.  You can echo the SQL statements from your application to get the running order.

You could also try testing the same sequence of SQL statements from the MySQL client, or through [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).

Are your history tables in the same database?

Comment: Yeah, in the future I will probably use PDO, I've just always used the mysql functions up until the current project.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql transactions only work using the mysqli API (not the classic methods). I have been using transactions. All I do is deactivate autocommit and run my SQL statements.

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
```

SELECT, INSERT, DELETE all are supported. as long as Im using the same mysqli handle to call these statements, they are within the transaction wrapper. nobody outside (not using the same mysqli handle) will see any data that you write/delete using INSERT/DELETE as long as the transaction is still open. So its critical you make sure every SQL statement is fired with that handle. Once the transaction is committed, data is made available to other db connections.

```
$mysqli->commit();
```