# How can I detect if a MYSQL query fails, and run a second MYSQL query when this happens? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm capturing information from a single PHP form to be recorded in two tables...

What I want is to have both records written or none at all (i.e., if one goes through and the other fails, remove the one that went through)

I wanted to know if there was a way I can detect a failure (possibly using 'or die'?) of the second query, and use this as a trigger to delete the record entered in the first query (or if there is a better method of achieving this)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples) about transactions.

Also note that to use transactions, your database storage engine needs to support them, you can´t use transactions if your table uses the MyISAM storage engine, you will need something like InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Look into database transactions.

Answer (score 1):

use [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just save the result in a variable and check it with "if"

```
$result = mysql_query( 'your query...' );
if( $result ) {
     echo 'Everything went fine';
} else {
     mysql_query( 'do other stuff' );
}
```