# How to do a INSERT with two different loops?

Tags: php, mysql

### Update

I have updated my code according to phant0m's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650112/how-to-do-a-insert-with-two-different-loops/6650501#6650501). It still doesn't quite work yet, though: `question_id` is always 0 in the database, even though it's not in the array:

```
var_dump($_POST['question_id'])
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "22" [1]=> string(2) "23" }
```

The query:

```
string(122) "INSERT INTO student_score(course_uid, student_uid, question_uid, answer) VALUES
(1, 4, 0, 'answer1'), 
(1, 4, 0, 'answer4')
```

This is the new code:

```
$sql_data = array();
$sql_prefix = "INSERT INTO student_score(course_uid, student_uid, question_uid, answer) VALUES";
foreach($_POST['answer'] as $id => $answer){
    // don't use $_REQUEST!
    $course_id = (int) $_POST['course_id'][$i];
    $student_id  = (int) $_POST['student_id'][$i];
    $question_id   = (int) $_POST['question_id'][$i];
    $answer      = mysql_real_escape_string($answer);
    $sql_data[] = "($course_id, $student_id, $question_id, '$answer')";
}
$sql = $sql_prefix.implode(", \n", $sql_data);
var_dump($sql);
if(!mysql_db_query($dbName, $sql, $connect)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Could not save information, Please try again";
    header("Location:student_assignment.php");
    //replaced die with else clause
}
else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Question successfully created";
    header("Location:student_assignment.php");
}
```

---

*Initial question*:

I have a problem adding the values of an array into a mysql database. The thing is
I have two loops and if I add the INSERT in one of the then the other one gives the wrong value. But if I echo inside each loop it gives the right values.

At the moment it adds two double rows of each value where I only want one row of each value.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  require_once("settings.inc.php");

  // require_once("student_session.inc.php");
  session_start();

  for ($d = 0; $d <= count($_POST[answer]); $d++) {
      $answer = $_POST[answer][$d];//I want to insert this value          
      //echo $answer;
      $ids = $_REQUEST['question_id'];

      foreach ($ids as $value) {
          //echo $value; //and this value into the INSERT              
          $sql = "INSERT INTO student_score(answer) VALUES ('$answer')";
          $results = mysql_db_query($dbName, $sql, $connect);
      }
  }

  if (!$results) {
      $_SESSION['msg'] = "Could not save information, Please try again";          
      header("Location:student_assignment.php");          
      die;
  }    

  $_SESSION['msg'] = "Question successfully created";      
  header("Location:student_assignment.php");

  die;
?>
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code so only the relevant part remains? Please try to explain your problem better. Also: Nobody wants to read unindented code!

Comment: Sorry this is my first post, on the submit page there is a for loop that gets the array of the answers selected. Then there is a foreach that get the question id's. My question is how will I get the values of the loops into a INSERT query multiple times?

Comment: You can loop through the array multiple times. Anyway, I suggest you take a look at multi-insert statements. What you are doing is highly inefficient.

Comment: What do you mean inefficient?What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The only thing I want to do is add the values in the loop into a database.

Comment: You send a query for every INSERT, you could to a batch-insert for example.

Comment: How would I do that sorry to bother, I have been busy with this since yesterday.not even google is helping.

Comment: My code shows you how to insert multiple entries at once.

Comment: Can you please put all debugging code in at once? Also: Add `echo "\nvariable: ".$question_id."\nPOST: ".$_POST['question_id'][$i]."\n";` below `$sql_data[]` and then copy the results from *source view*

Comment: variable: 0
POST: 

variable: 0
POST:

Comment: that's what I got adding that line of code

Comment: Can someone please help me I have tried everything :'(

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong variable:

```
"INSERT INTO student_score(answer) VALUES ('$answer')";
```

You comment that the variable you'd like inserted is called `$value`, so you meant to write:

```
"INSERT INTO student_score(answer) VALUES ".
       "('".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."')";
```

(`mysql_real_escape_string` is to prevent SQL injection attacks)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make much sense.

This might more closely resemble what you want it to do:

```
// you will not want <=, that will create an index error upon the last 
// iteration, also, you need to quote the key!
// This is fixed:
//for ($d = 0; $d < count($_POST['answer']); $d++) {
// this is a better way
// this assumes, that the indices of the POST array nicely correspond with each 
// other.
$sql_data = array();
$sql_prefix = "INSERT INTO student_score(question_id, student_id, course_id, answer) VALUES";
foreach($_POST['answer'] as $id => $anwer){
    // don't use $_REQUEST!
    $question_id = (int) $_POST['question_id'][$i];
    $student_id  = (int) $_POST['student_id'][$i];
    $course_id   = (int) $_POST['course_id'][$i];
    $answer      = your_escape_function($answer)
    $sql_data[] = "($question_id, $student_id, $course_id, '$answer')";
}
$sql = $sql_prefix.implode(", \n", $sql_data);
if(!mysql_db_query($dbName, $sql, $connect)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Could not save information, Please try again";
    header("Location:student_assignment.php");
    //replaced die with else clause
}
else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Question successfully created";
    header("Location:student_assignment.php");
}
```

### Attention

This code is mostly based on guesswork and assumptions what you want it to do.
You need to have a function that properly escapes your code based on whether `magic_quotes` are enabled. Simply calling `mysql_real_escape_string()`as suggested in the other answer is **incorrect**.

Please note that mysql_* functions are outdated. Consider using parameterized queries using PDOs or myqsli.

PS: do not use `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, everything works fine except the question id is 0 in the database. Would you maybe know why?

Comment: I suggest you add `var_dump($_POST['question_id']);` above the `foreach`-line. Post back the output.

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "22" [1]=> string(2) "23" } array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "22" [1]=> string(2) "23" } array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "22" [1]=> string(2) "23" } array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "22" [1]=> string(2) "23" }

Comment: Hmm... this is certainly interesting. It should be converted to an integer without problems with (int). Could you post back the output of  `var_dump($sql);` by inserting it above `if(!mysql_db_query()` ?

Comment: string(122) "INSERT INTO student_score(course_uid, student_uid, question_uid, answer) VALUES(1, 4, 0, 'answer1'), (1, 4, 0, 'answer4')"

Comment: Ah, you have adjusted my code. Can you update your initial question and *add* the modified code at the bottom please, so I can see the modifications.

Comment: I added the code to my original code, Sorry for the layout I don't know how to add it in code view. The only things I changed was the column names and the order.

Comment: @Annuscha: Oh sorry, that drowned in my inbox... Yes, let me think a little ;)

Answer (score 0):

make use of MySQL transactions:
[PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)

Also can you post the output of the following?:
print_r($_POST); and print_r($_POST[answer]);

Using  $_REQUEST is bad Idea. either use POST or GET explicitly!

Comment: why is using $_REQUEST is bad Idea?

Comment: Because you don't know whether it is post or Get. Suppose the same file receives form but one via Get and another POST using same index, how do you differentiate? It is bad practice--->be explicit!

Comment: @Lawrence, but `$_REQUEST` also includes stuff from `$_SESSION`. Also, `$_POST` is shorter to type.

Comment: @Lawrence: Your argumentation is invalid. By default, the order is "gpc", i.e. `GET` has the highest priority. A user could be sent a link to a form, and depending what the `action` is set to, the `GET` parameters may be preserved and thereby overriding a value by the user. $_REQUEST also makes debugging harder, because you never really know which value you were originally refering to. There is **no** benefit in using it. As already mentioned, it's also longer... so be pragmatic at least ;) @TRiG: No it doesn't. It may also contain content from `$_COOKIE`