# How to combine two unrelated SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have two SQL queries:

```
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('', 'mike', '21')

DELETE FROM tableB WHERE name = 'john'
```

And I want to execute them at the same time. How do I do that?
I know that UNION only works for SELECT statements, so it's useless in this case.

Comment: "And I want to execute them at the same time" --- any **real** reason to want that? Or is it just a caprice

Comment: I'm making a scheduled event in MySQL that executes every 24 hours and has to do a lot of stuff. I'll either have to make a big query or I'll have to make multiple events...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create a transaction.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html

```
START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('', 'mike', '21');
  DELETE FROM tableB WHERE name = 'john';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Great, it was simpler than I thought. Thanks to everyone that answered!

Answer (score 0):

Write a [stored procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx) that encapsulates these statements and call that from your application.

Answer (score 0):

Put all statements in a stored procedure and call that procedure instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into using transactions. This is the `A` (atomicity) in the [`ACID` properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) that guarantee transactional integrity in databases, meaning that either *all* of a transaction will happen or *none* of it will.

Check out [the latest docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html) for a description of how this works. Basically, it's:

```
start transaction
do your first operation
do your second operation
commit
```

And, with proper isolation, the changes won't be visible to the outside world until the commit is done.

Comment: "the relational database ACID properties" is almost certainly a misstatement. Hints: 'database' = the collection of data, 'DBMS' = the software system managing the data, 'relational' = a word not found in the SQL Standard specs. Suggestion: replace "relational database" with "DBMS".

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute them both at exactly the same time, but I'm guessing you're asking this because you only want to run the second query if the first one succeeds. This can be achieved by using transactions. There are some good examples is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2708237/196838) question.