# Execute multiple MySQL queries 

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 sql queries to execute, but I want it to execute all or if error in one query then dont execute any. I'm using php. I used to use try and catch in .NET but I'm new to php.

Below is the code which i was trying to do:

```
function Registration($UserFirstname,$UserLastname){
$sql="INSERT INTO table1 (fieldname1,fieldname2) VALUES ('$UserFirstname','$UserLastname')";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$sql="INSERT INTO table2 (fieldname1,fieldname2) VALUES ('$UserFirstname','$UserLastname')";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());}
```

Comment: Database transactions are your friend :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples. The accepted answer on the link uses `try` and `catch`.

Comment: Hi Anand,i came across this method but im not using object oriented programming in my code.Thanks for the comment :D

Comment: You can use database transactions in imperative programming as well. Just start the transaction ("START TRANSACTION;") and commit it ("COMMIT;") when you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're probably facing with `try...catch` is that PHP has two different error handling mechanisms: [error reporting](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php) and [exceptions](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). You cannot catch exceptions unless the underlying code throws them and good old `mysql_query()` will trigger warnings rather than throwing exceptions. There're several workarounds but, if you are interested in writing good object-oriented code, I suggest you switch to [PDO](http://es.php.net/pdo).

In any case, if you want to stick to good old MySQL library, your code should basically work:

```
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

The explanation:

- `mysql_query()` returns `FALSE` if the query fails (e.g., you get a duplicate key)
- The right side of the `or` expression will only execute if the left side is `FALSE`
- `die()` aborts the script, thus preventing the next queries to be executed

However, I presume that you don't want to abort in the middle of nowhere. If we add some missing bits (such as proper SQL generation and code indentation) we get this:

```
function Registration($UserFirstname,$UserLastname){
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO table1 (fieldname1,fieldname2) VALUES ('%s','%s')";
        mysql_real_escape_string($UserFirstname),
        mysql_real_escape_string($UserLastname)
    );
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if( !$res ){
        return FALSE;
    }


    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO table2 (fieldname1,fieldname2) VALUES ('%s','%s')";
        mysql_real_escape_string($UserFirstname),
        mysql_real_escape_string($UserLastname)
    );
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if( !$res ){
        return FALSE;
    }


    return TRUE;
}
```

## About transactions

Please note that you still need to use transactions if there's a chance that the **second** query fails. Transactions are not particularly difficult to use, the only requirements are:

1. Define the involved tables as InnoDB
2. Run a `START TRANSACTION` query on top of the function
3. Run a `COMMIT` query at the end of the function

Comment: I think ill use this as its simpler for me and im not using transaction ,Thanks @Alvaro G.Vicario

Comment: @Prasaanth - Please note that you still need to use transactions if there's a chance that the **second** query fails. Transactions are not particularly difficult to use. Seriously.

Comment: PDO (if available) is always worth using because the prepared statements protect against injection while avoiding mysql_real_escape_string pollution of the code.

Comment: This code still has the same problem the originally posted code had - it can leave the database in an inconsistent state if the first query succeeds but the second query fails.  You either have to manually delete the newly inserted row created by the first statement, or wrap the whole thing up in a transaction.

Comment: @GordonM - That's too an important piece of info to remain hidden in comments. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using transactions.  These allow you to wrap a set of queries in a block that says "Either all these queries execute successfully or none of them do".  This means that no matter what happens in the transaction block, you can be sure that the integrity of your database has been maintained.

NOTE: Transactions don't work with MyISAM tables, you have to use InnoDB tables.

```
mysql_query ('BEGIN TRANSACTION;', $db);
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO sometable (some, columns) VALUES ($some, $values)", $db);
if ($errMsg = mysql_error ($db))
{
    mysql_query ('ROLLBACK;', $db);
    die ($errMsg);
}
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO someothertable (some, other, columns) VALUES ($some, $other, $values)", $db);
if ($errMsg = mysql_error ($db))
{
    mysql_query ('ROLLBACK;', $db);
    die ($errMsg);
}
mysql_query ('COMMIT', $db);
```

Comment: Hi GordonM,this is what i am looking for.what is MyISAM/InnoDB tables if you dont mind me asking.

Comment: MyIsam and InnoDB are the [storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html) behind MySQL tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) 
Or you can change your DB schema to InnoDB..

Answer (score 0):

For executing two queries as one, you have to use mysql extension, my below code works well

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```