# Run multiple SQL statements at once in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have this:

```
<?php
   $length = count($data['mark']);
   $i=0;
   $s=1;
   for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
       $sql="UPDATE `groupdatabase1` .`questions` SET `mark`=".$data['mark'][$i].", `feedback`= '".$data['feedback'][$i]."' WHERE `question`= ".$s." ;";
       mysql_query($sql);
       echo $sql;
   }
?>
```

I have an unknown amount of queries to run from this, meaning multiple queries in succession. How do I go about running them all one after another?

Comment: First fix up your sql injection vulnerabilities. After that, what you've got will run all those queries, one afte rthe other. But you have no error checking whatsoever, which'll make it impossible to figure out why 1 (or more) of your zillions of queries failed.

Comment: Your code is doing that right now, in the loop. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Googleisyourfriend : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198707/running-multiple-php-scripts-at-the-same-time-database-loop-issue (one of the first link) if you want to launch at the same time. If it is not that I don't understand the question.

Comment: You *are* running multiple SQL queries one after another.  What's the issue here?

Comment: Marc B do you mean by putting escape strings? 

And the code can run one query but I need a way of essentially conjoining multiple queries

Comment: I believe he wants to know how to run the updates concurrently rather than serially.

Comment: @Rafe: In his title he says "at once", but in the question he says "one after another".

Comment: @user1248092: you can't run multiple separate queries in a single mysql_query() call. The mysql driver for PHP does not allow it as a simple sql injection attack prevention method.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[PDO](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**, **[Prepared Statements](http://il.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)** and **[Transactions](http://il.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php)**.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: How does it not? I've listed everything needs to be done to solve the problem, one by one, and included pages to the relevant documentation. If he can't RTFM, this question isn't really worth solving (because he wouldn't have learned anything from it).

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query only allows one query per call, even if you use ';'
so you will have to do several mysql_query calls, one for each query you want to run.