# Can I compare a php date to a mysql date on insert?

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

This is my working query for inserting to mysql from my php page:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO postings (title, description, timeStamp) VALUES ( '$title', '$description', STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%a, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s'))";
```

What I'm hoping to do is now only insert if $date is greater than the most recent date in mysql.timeStamp (type of timestamp).

Can I do this?  I've tried the following:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO postings (title, description, timeStamp) VALUES ( '$title', '$description', STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%a, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s')) where STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%a, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s') > timeStamp";
```

1)  Can I compare a date from my php page to a mysql date on insert?
2)  If so...  How would I finish this query and make " > timeStamp" only evaluate the most recent date in the table (assuming the rest of my where clause works)?

Comment: if you use unix timestamps what your trying to do will be alot easier/efficient .  At least for this sort of thing.  Much easier to compare int values than all the work converting strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better if you first run a query to check if there are posts with a higher timestamp in your table before inserting the row. You can do this with this query:

```
$query = "SELECT 1 FROM postings 
    WHERE STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%a, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s') < timeStamp
    LIMIT 1";
```

Then if no results are returned you can insert your post as normal.

Comment: great idea!  i'll head down this road.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to surround my normal insert statement with the following.  I have 1 result that I know should be true..  but nothing is being inserted.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$querycheck = "SELECT 1 FROM postings WHERE city=$city and STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%a, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s') > timeStamp LIMIT 1"; if ($querycheck === true) { my original insert statement here }`

Answer (score 0):

1) No, you can't. You can check the sintax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

You can use a transaction to avoid concurrency of @rabusmar solution, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples) some samples

You can also use a stored procedure, but is more complicated than a transaction and has same result.