# primary key and foreign key in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i really need some help down here with these primary keys and foreign keys.I've tried searching for leads but i'm not able to figure it out. Please help me out here and i'm sorry if this question has been asked before

i've got 2 tables and their columns

**client** 
id(pk) | organisation | description | token

**Transaction**
trx_id | c_id(fk) | trx_description | trx_date | action | no_of_token

In the transaction table, all the values in it were manually key in by me through php myadmin even selecting the c_id which is the foreign key.so my question is for example i create a new organisation called ccc, i want it to get automatically assigned to the c_id of 3 in the transaction table.Also everytime i update the tokens, it should display in the trasaction table as trx_id(i already set it as auto increament)
 but the c_id should match the organisation i've selected and increment the row accordingly.........Hope you guys can help me out quick and i'm sorry if i'm confusing you......I can post the code if you guys want :)

This script below add the client

```
<?php 

include 'connection.php';

// Get values from form
$organisation=$_POST['organisation'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$token=$_POST['token'];


// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO client(organisation, description, token)VALUES('$organisation', '$description', '$token')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='login_success.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

transaction table script

```
    <?php 

include 'connection.php';

?>  
<html>
<head>
<title>ThaiCreate.Com PHP & MySQL Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="add.php?id=<?=$_GET["id"];?>" name="frmEdit" method="POST">
<?
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE id = '".$_GET["id"]."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if(!$objResult)
{
echo "Not found id=".$_GET["id"];
}
else
{
?>
<table width="600" border="1">
<tr>
<th width="91"> <div align="center">id </div></th>
<th width="160"> <div align="center">organisation </div></th>
<th width="198"> <div align="center">current token </div></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?=$objResult["id"];?></div></td>
<td><?=$objResult["organisation"];?></td>
<td><?=$objResult["token"];?></td>
</tr>
</table>

How many tokens do you want to add to this organisation: <input type="text" id="newToken" name="newToken" /><br/>
Please fill up the reason for adding the tokens : <input type="text" id="reason" name="reason" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

<? 

$newToken = isset($_POST['newToken']) ? $_POST["newToken"] : "";
$reason = isset($_POST['reason']) ? $_POST["reason"] : "";


$sql="UPDATE client SET token = token + '$newToken' WHERE id = '".$_GET["id"]."' ";

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error Query [".$sql."]");
?>

<?

if ($newToken == true)
{

mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$query_string_count = "SELECT count(*) AS num FROM transaction WHERE c_id =" . $_GET["id"]; 
  $query = mysql_query($query_string_count);
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);

  $num = $objResult["num"];

  INSERT INTO `transaction` (`trx_id`, `c_id`, `trx_description`, `trx_date`, `action`, `no_of_token`) VALUES ($num + 1, $_GET["id"], '$reason', '".$date."', 'Add token', '$newToken')";

  mysql_query("COMMIT TRANSACTION");





?>

<?
header("Location:login_success.php"); 
}
else {



}
?>

<?

}
mysql_close();

?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do i post my script here should i do it under the comments part

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set up the trx_id as auotoincrement.
If you need keep separated the number of transcation of each client then the trx_id shouldn't be autoincrement.

For example each time you do insert on the transaction table:

1: start new transcation
2: number = count the number transactions that has as c_id the id of the client of interest
3: insert into transaction and set trx_id = number + 1
4: commit transaction

Note: in this case trx_id could not unique as you have more clients. If you need it you can insert a new column in the transaction table that is primary_key and in this case autoincrement

Here a snapshot of code to do what i described:

```
    //new db transaction
  mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

  // count number of transaction for clients $_GET["id"]
  $query_string_count = "SELECT count(*) AS num FROM transactions WHERE c_id =" . $_GET["id"]; 
  $query = mysql_query($query_string_count);
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);

  $num = $objResult["num"];

  //insert new transaction for client $_GET["id"] with id $num + 1
  INSERT INTO `transaction` (`trx_id`, `c_id`, `trx_description`, `trx_date`, `action`, `no_of_token`) VALUES ($num + 1, $_GET["id"], '$reason', '".$date."', 'Add token', '$newToken')";

   //COMMIT -> persist on db
   mysql_query("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
```

Comment: OP might also be interested to know why and how to use transactions and that he needs `InnoDB` as table engine to use them. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html and same examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples

Comment: so right now what i have is that for inserting into the clients table its
 $sql="INSERT INTO client(organisation, description, token)VALUES('$organisation', '$description', '$token')";

and inserting into transaction table its

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "INSERT INTO `transaction` (`trx_id`, `c_id`, `trx_description`, `trx_date`, `action`, `no_of_token`) VALUES ('$reason', '".$date."', 'Add token', '$newToken')";
  
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
$result=mysql_query($sql)

Comment: i just posted the new code.....i'm sorry if i'm just using your code but i'm pretty desperate and lost for now....

Comment: :) that's why forums exist. However for production code always sanitize the input you receive: mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]); $organisation= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['organisation']); and so on for each $_GET or $_POST value you use

Comment: Is there any way for me to get in touch wid you to explain this more......i really need this help asap......its my job.....i'm so sorry

Comment: ho sir i'm not able to view your email.Could you kindly pls go over to my profile and send me a test mail pls.

Comment: i'm really sorry for the trouble

Comment: same for me, can't see your mail post it here i'll write you