# INSERT and SELECT in single query MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can I do one single query with both an INSERT and SELECT in it *and then read the results of selection*?
I want to insert and then select something, all must be done in one query...

I know it accept multiple commands in single query...But I want to read results of query and I cannot read results. I'm doing this:

```
$results=mysql_query("
INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2) VALUES('aaa','bbbb') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `field1` = 'cccc', `field2`='dddddd'; 
SELECT field3 Form Table3 WHERE field3='eeeee';
",$connection);

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM))  
echo $rows[0];
```

Comment: [Docs](http://php.net/mysql_query): _"mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)..."_ Instead, I think you're wanting a _transaction_.

Comment: Why can't you simply do 2 queries? So you can even check result of insert?

Comment: From the performance perspective, you will not achieve anything with this. Just call mysql_query two times. Why "all must be done in one query..."?

Comment: I want to select the same row I inserted in a single query. Is it possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to send multiple statements in PHP if you are using the [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension, which is a good idea to use instead of the older mysql extension for a lot of reasons.  Here is a modified example from the [multiple statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) section of the documentation, based on your question:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

$sql .= "INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2) VALUES('aaa','bbbb') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `field1` = 'cccc', `field2`='dddddd';";
$sql .= "SELECT field3 Form Table3 WHERE field3='eeeee';";

$mysqli->multi_query($sql);

do {
    if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        $res->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
?>
```

Notice that the documentation does dedicate airtime to security risks of multiple statements, which everyone is pointing out.  The other reason, of course, that it's not always a great idea is if you want the second statement to be affected by the first statement.

Answer (score 5):

> all must be done in one query...

Why do you *need* to do everything in **one** query ?

Like Wiseguy said, I think what you are looking for is called a transaction.

Also, It might be a good idea considering updating to PDO, which will give you a more complete toolset like transactions and query parameters.

Anyway, for answering your initial question, no it is not possible.

**Update:** Here is an example of a transaction in PDO.

```
try
{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    $pdo->query(' ... ');
    $pdo->query(' ... ');
    $pdo->query(' ... ');

    $pdo->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $pdo->rollback();
    die($e->getCode() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use a try-catch (which I like), don't forget to set  [PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) so that it will throw exceptions; I don't think it does by default. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2708247/185544) has a nearly identical example with more info about that.

Comment: You are right about PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, I did forget about that !

Answer (score 3):

Not possible, and wouldnt recommend doing it either, as kappa points out, if you perform 2 seperate queries you'll be able to check for results etc. which is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this either but you can use pdo to do this as shown in this thread: [PDO support for multiple queries (PDO_MYSQL, PDO_MYSQLND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd)