# In PHP & MySql programming how to executive more then 3 queries in a single statement?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to execute a more then 3 queries in a single statement.
is is possible?

i need to insert the values into the table
   select entire table
   count the users.

is it possible to do all these in a single statement.

Thanks

Comment: that sounds like two statements, but no, that's not possible in a single statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9927097/1894905

Comment: insert into table/select * from table/select count(*) from users

Comment: can we implement this concept in mysql without using mysqli

Comment: @Doc what do you mean? please read the question!

Comment: phoenix said 3 queries and jack said that there were only 2, so i pointed out the 3 queries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more than 3 queries only in mysqli using [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli-multi-query), but mysql doesn't support it.

Comment: Don't forget to remind the security concerns: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: can we implement this concept in mysql without using mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Example code :

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Change it accordingly. It shows multiquery in action using mysqli.

Comment: i need to implement in mysql with out using mysqli