# insert and update in different database in one php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

how can i update and insert together

```
        require_once ('database.php'); 

$name = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["name"]);
$course = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["course"]);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["email"]);
$contact = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["contact"]);
$Date = mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["Date"]);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM registerlist WHERE name = '" . $name . "'";
$result = mysql_query ($sql, $dbconn); 

if (mysql_num_rows ($result) > 0) {
    $resultStr = header("Location:blog.php");

} else {

    $result = "SELECT * FROM courselist WHERE cname = '" . $course 
    . "'";
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registerlist (name, Course, Email, Contact, 
  Date) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $course . "', '" . $email . "', '" . 
   $contact . "','" . $date . "')";

    $result1= mysql_query($sql, $dbconn);
 $result =mysql_query("UPDATE courselist SET $Row['slot'] = 
           '$Row['slot'] - 1 '");
    if ($result1) {
    $resultStr = header("Location:blog.php");

    } 

  }

  echo json_encode($resultStr);
```

if the person register the course, the course slot will subract by 1 and student document will be insert into registerlist database.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Be sure to use prepared statements and parameter binding, so **you'll never have to worry about quoting issues again.**

Comment: Check out  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927097/insert-and-select-in-single-query-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you connect to multiple MySQL databases on a single webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I did understand correctly: You want to update the `courselist` table at the same time a record was insert into the `registerlist` table? This can be done using triggers (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html , IF both databases run at the same SQL server) and/or table locks (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html):

1. Without trigger

   - Lock table `courselist`
   - Insert the record to `registerlist`
   - Update table `courselist`
   - Release table `courselist`
2. With trigger
   You need a trigger that locks the table `courselist` before writing to the `registerlist` table, and a trigger that updates `courselist` and releases the lock after writing to `registerlist`.
   In this case you only insert the record into `registerlist` from your PHP code, and the table locking and `courselist` update is being done by the triggers within the SQL server.

In any case you can't write to both tables at the same time, there is no SQL statement to do that. But with locks you can simulate such a behavior.

When defining the target table of a SQL statement, you may prepend the tables database name like `databaseName.tableName`, if the Connection uses a different database per Default.

But aynber from the comments is absolutely right - you should move away from `mysql_*` asap!

**Edit**: This SQL example should show how table locking is working (all information about that can be found in the MySQL documentation from the link above):

```
LOCK TABLES courselist WRITE;
INSERT INTO registerlist …;
UPDATE courselist …;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

You'll Need a `WRITE` lock, since you're going to write to the table. Other reading, writing or locking statements from other sessions are blocked until you release the lock.

A `READ` lock would prevent the table from being modified by any session. Writing (and write locking) attempts are blocked until you release the lock and all other `READ` locks from other sessions are released, too.

Comment: how can i create the lock ? i am new to mysql

Comment: @qqqss I updated my post with a SQL example and a little basic locking information.