# How exactly do transactions with PHP PDO work with concurrency?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo, acid

I'm making a webapp where they'll be multiple users interacting with each other and reading/making decisions on/modifying shared data.

I've read that transactions are atomic, which is what I need. However, I'm not sure how it works with the PHP `PDO::beginTransaction()`

I mean atomic as in if one transaction is editing some data, all other transactions also modifying/reading that data will need to wait until the first transaction finishes. Like I don't want two scripts reading a value, incrementing the old one, and effectively storing only one increment. The second script should have to wait for the first one to finish.

In almost all the examples I've seen the queries are used consecutively (example [PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)). A lot of what I'm doing requires

- querying and fetching
- checking that data, and acting on it, as part of the same transaction

---

1. **Will the transaction still work atomically if there is PHP code between queries?**
2. **I know you should prepare your statements outside the transaction, but is it okay to prepare it inside? Basically, I'm worried about PHP activity ruining the atomicity of a transaction.**

Here's an example (this one doesn't require checking a previous value). I have a very basic inbox system which stores mail as a serialized array (if someone has a better recommendation please let me know). So I query for it, append the new message, and store it. Will it work as expected?

```
$getMail = $con->prepare('SELECT messages FROM inboxes WHERE id=?');
$storeMail = $con->prepare('UPDATE inboxes SET messages=? WHERE id=?');
$con->beginTransaction();
$getMail->execute(array($recipientID));
$result = $getMail->fetch();
$result = unserialize($result[0]);
$result[] = $msg;
$storeMail->execute(array(serialize($result), $recipientID));
$con->commit();
```

Comment: I think it's a good idea that you explain your understanding of Atomicity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Transactions are atomic only with respect to other database connections trying to use the same data, i.e. other connections will see either *no* changes made by your transaction, or *all* changes; "atomic" meaning no other database connection will see an in-between state with some data updated and other not.

PHP code between queries won't break atomicity, and it does not matter where you prepare your statements.

Comment: Hmmmm. But can other transactions read data while I'm in the middle of the transaction? Since if I'm in the middle of a transaction and someone's reading the old value that often defeats the purpose of proper-concurrency. Sorry if I'm not getting you right

Comment: You probably need [`SELECT FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) or [serializable transaction isolation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html)

Comment: I saw them before but hoped I could get away with just transactions haha. I've taken another look into `select for update`, but cannot seem to figure when does the lock release. After the next update? When/after the transaction commits?

Comment: Direct copy from the referenced docs: `All locks set by LOCK IN SHARE MODE and FOR UPDATE queries are released when the transaction is committed or rolled back.`

Comment: Dear me. Sorry about such trivial questions. Anyways, thanks! Answered all my questions