# mysql - insert id from parent table

Tags: php, mysql

I have table definitions:

```
create table users(
                  id int not null auto_increment, 
                  usernaname varchar(50) not null, 
                  pass varchar(50) not null,
                  primary key(id)
                  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
create table users_description(
                  user_id int not null, 
                  description varchar(255),
                  key(user_id), 
                  foreign key(user_id) references users(id) on delete cascade
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and it is good, works nice.

but when I add a new user I use a next query:

```
insert into users (username, pass) values('test', 'test');
```

but how to add a id of user automatically in users_description table? 
Something similar to to this:

```
insert into users_description values(
                                    select id from users where username = 'test',
                                     'user description');
```

I want to use only two queries, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the last inserted primary key id (which would be from the `users` table):

```
INSERT INTO users_description VALUES 
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'test', 'user description');
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.. But is this safe? I mean if something goes wrong, maybe first query fails or something other.. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @consigliere you should encase both inserts within a transaction, so if the first insert fails, you can do a rollback to ensure your data is kept consistent.

Comment: Is this examle from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples) good enough to kept my data consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. [**Example here.**](http://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=56)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("insert form (username, pass) values('test', 'test')");
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

gives you the last inserted id in PHP ..