# MySQL PHP lock table, is there a better solution when expacting simultaneously connections

Tags: php, mysql

has any one a better solution for me for that code:

```
<?php

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->beginTransaction();

    $dbh->exec("LOCK TABLES test2 WRITE");

    $row = $dbh->query('SELECT * from test2 WHERE c > 0 LIMIT 1');

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE test2 SET c=c-1 WHERE a=:a and c>0");
    $stmt->bindParam(':a', $row['a']);
    $stmt->execute();

    /**
    ...
    ....
    .....
    **/

    $dbh->exec("UNLOCK TABLES");

    $dbh->commit();
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log("Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n", 3, "./my-errors.log");
    exit();
}
```

When i get simultaneously connections to that script, every connection should have his own row from the table test2 (field A).

Thanks for your ideas :-)

Comment: Why not do your `UPDATE` all in one query?

Comment: Have you tried using transactions?
Here's a few examples:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples

Comment: I do not think transactions will work. I tested them allready. `$dbh->beginTransaction();` There are no database violations so the transaction wont throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to know `a` parameter, you can use following query

```
UPDATE test2 SET c=c-1 WHERE c>0 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I need to know the `a` parameter to do some other stuff

Answer (score 0):

`LOCK TABLES` and `UNLOCK TABLES` close your transaction automatically. You need a [`SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) and forget lock and unlock tables.

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` locks at row level. Other executions of the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` will wait for the end of the first transition if they pretend obtain the same record.