# Restore recent mysql values

Tags: php, mysql

The situation: i make some changes in the database, then do some code and then return to the initial values ​​of the affected rows. Is it possible to restore rows to the recent values after changes with some function?

As i see it now: read all the data into an array, then perform the necessary changes and return an array of all the data back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `InnoDB` or other engines that support transactions, you can do:

```
mysql_query('SET AUTOCOMMIT=0');
mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');
// TODO make some changes...
mysql_query('ROLLBACK');
mysql_query('SET AUTOCOMMIT=1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way, have a "original_value" and "current_value" in your table and keep "original_value" unchanged.

Use "current_value" for your problem and when you need to restore, update the table to make "current_value" back to "original_value"

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use Transactions in your code? Take a look at this post [PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)