# Is there any way to have something returned by executing a DELETE directive in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

Basically, I have two SQL `DELETE` queries that a PHP script processes. However, I want the second query to be executed only if the first one successfully deletes a row in the designated table.
So is there anyways to have the `mysql_query()` function return true or false or something, after executing the first query?

If there is no way to do so, then I've already come up with a method for achieving the result I want. However, being able to do it this way would be much simpler, and make much more sense as far as the logic of my code is concerned.

Comment: Please, stop using `mysql_query`. This is an interface from the 1990s that's being phased out and may not be supported in the future. Use `mysqli` or PDO before you create a mess that will take forever and a half to clean up. [It's not that hard to pick up](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and will save you a lot of trouble in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
delete ....
select row_count()
```

That will give you the number of rows deleted (or 0 if none).
For more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something a little more official like transactions with mySQL.

There is a useful post on the [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2708247/892792) about this very situation.