# how UPDATE mysql row plus one and get the value

Tags: php, mysql

I updated with success

```
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET `queue2` = `queue2` + 1 WHERE `id` = '$getid'");
```

but how can I get the "queue2" value without opening a new request to MySQL

I can simply get the new value with this command

```
$selresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `id` = '$getid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

but I'm afraid that the database can get new update again and i will get higher number

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: As stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Answer (score 0):

See URL:-

[PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)

Try this:-

```
printf ("Updated records: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

Comment: this part worked for me, like i said... i want to get the  "queue2 +1" value

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a transaction between the queries to be certain.

The docs for transactions [are here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html). A good SO question that covers it in detail: [PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)

Edit:

Looking at it from a different angle, why don't you do it in reverse though? It might save the need for a transaction (thought it is possible that you get multiple reads before a write):

Get the value for your `queue2` value to display in the page from this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `id` = '$getid'");
```

You have the true value now, so you can run:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET `queue2` = `queue2` + 1 WHERE `id` = '$getid'");
```

No transaction and you know the value of the data before the update.

Comment: @Kirma See edit, might solve all your problems without the need for a transaction.

Comment: because i'm afraid that 2 people can get the same value.. and when you actually perform +1 and get the value there is no way that people will get the same value

Comment: Then to resume it all: the only way to have a UNIQUE number for each connection/client is using LOCKING (or a MySQL primary key).

Answer (score 0):

you can use query to update the value.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE user_profile SET userpoints = userpoints + 1 WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'");
```

Comment: He has that bit down pat - he wants to know that no other query has updated the row in the meantime before his second query.