# simultaneous data entry to multiple SQL tables from PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to edit and save data as coded below simultaneously to two different tables? Just look at the code which enters data to the data tables.

```
        if($opt>=$rec['gwstart'] && $opt<=$rec['gwend'])
        {


        $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die ("Server connection failure!"); 
        $db=mysql_select_db('regional_data',$con) or die ("Couldn't connect the  database"); 
        $SQL22="UPDATE newchk SET totgw=$AAA where gwstart=$BBB"; 
        $run22=mysql_query($SQL22,$con) or die ("SQL Error"); 

        $SQL33="INSERT INTO invoentry (user_inv,dist_inv,chkNum,InvoNum,InvoVal,InvoDate,DueDate,type,condition) VALUES ('$naMex','$distUsr','$listVal','$InNo','$InValu','$date1','$date2','$typ','$cnd')"; 
        $run33 = mysql_query($SQL33,$con) or die ("SQL Error!..");
        $MSG ="Successfully saved your entry! ".$AAA." cheques are remaining.";
        }
```

Comment: Sure. Have you experienced any specific problems?

Comment: Use a transaction.
Execute both of your queries within it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples

Comment: Of course you can. As @LastCoder mentioned, transactions would be preferential in this case to ensure data integrity.

Comment: @deceze Yes. I can't save '$cnd' value to 'condition' and gives a SQL error message. I checked for my '<option>' name to be 'CPass' and assigning it to a variable as '$cnd=$_POST['CPass'];' but all seems fine. I know the error is writing the condition value to the database but can't figure out why the error message pops up!

Comment: Oh thanks I figured out an error with a database field. Anyways I changed to transaction method as you all described. Thank you.

Comment: Use `or die(mysql_error())` if you don't feel like stabbing into the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, if your queries are somehow related and you need to make sure they both succeed you can use SQL TRANSACTIONS. otherwise, as you already did, you can run multiple queries.