# PHP Mysql Updating positions and parents of an Id in a table

Tags: php, mysql

Please I have a table with three columns :

```
id   (this is the id of my table)
parent  (this is the parent)
position  (and this is the position)
```

And I have this array `$_arr['menu']` :

```
array (size=3)
  13 => 
    array (size=1)
      'parent' => string '0' (length=1)   
  14 => 
    array (size=1)  
      'parent' => string '13' (length=2) 
  25 => 
    array (size=1)  
      'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
```

I want to update may table with those values in the array **$_arr['menu']**.

I imagine to do something like but in one query (perhaps using case in) :

```
UPDATE table SET position = 1, parent = 0 WHERE id = 13;

UPDATE table SET position = 2, parent = 13 WHERE id = 14; 

UPDATE table SET position = 3, parent = 0 WHERE id = 25;
```

Please masters, how to get those values from that array and how to do the update !

Thanks a lot

Comment: u want make two updates in one update ?

Comment: Yes, In fact the array may have more than two !

Comment: And please how to get those values from the array !

Comment: post your array without explanation and your generated array

Comment: @SamiElHilali very sorry to say, but the things needed to 'solve' your 'problem' are the basics of programming with php/mysql...

Comment: @SamiElHilali you can use transaction. Here's a good example [transaction example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)
I know, it's not in one statement but you can prepare all those query in a loop and then run together in one transaction.

Comment: @dbf It's actually a very valid question, it seems you didn't see what basic *questions* really look like ;)

Comment: @mariami thank you but I need also how to extract values from that array. Thank you.

Comment: @jadkik94 for this post being tagged with PHP, I'm surprised not to find "what have you tried" comments of any kind. I don't see anything "tried" in his question, so explain how you think this is in your opinion a valid question...

Comment: @mariami why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I got your question, but I'll write my snippet. (I don't remember php syntax well and it's not tested, but I think it shows what I want to say)

```
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $increment = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $id => $innerArray) {
            $db->query("UPDATE table SET position = ".(++$increment).", parent = ".$innerArray['parent']." WHERE id =".$id);
    }
    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollback();
}
```

Comment: +1 for using transactions, but how do you know he's using PDO? Second, using `$db->prepare("query")` and bind the values as parameters would prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I wanted to show only the idea. Sure, the code must be corrected and the parameters should be set and not concatenated

Comment: And I got your Idea, You are just awesome mariami !

Comment: @dbf I'm using MySQLi. and his Idea was helpful !