# Return value using alias name

Tags: delphi, oracle11g, delphi-7, zeos

I wrote code like this :

```
sql1 :='select sum(jumlah) as debet from kasir_kas_transaksi where flag in (1,3) and tanggal = to_date('+quotedstr(after)+','+quotedstr('dd-mm-yyyy')+')';

with zquery1 do begin
  close;
  sql.clear;
  sql.Add(sql1);
  execSQL;
end;
edit1.Text:=zquery1.fieldbyname('debet').asstring;
```

then an error occured saying field 'debet' does not exist.
is there something wrong in the code?
I am using delphi 7 and zeos as connection, as well as oracle 11g as db. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use `Open`, not `ExecSQL`. `ExecSQL` is for queries that don't return result sets (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `UPDATE`). `Open` is for queries that return rows.
You also don't need to use `SQL.Clear;` and then `SQL.Add();` - you can just set `SQL.Text` directly instead.

(You should stop using `with`; that's a different topic, but I left it here because it's your code and not mine.)

```
with ZQuery1 do
begin
  SQL.Text := sql1;
  Open;
end;
Edit1.Text := ZQuery1.FieldByName('debet').AsString;
```

And as a note, stop concatenating SQL and use parameters instead. String concatenation with user input leaves you wide-open for SQL injection. Google *Little Bobby Tables* to find out why that's a bad thing if you don't know already. You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16761336/62576) of writing your code using parameters instead.

Comment: thank you so much for you help. I am super new at coding stuffs so I lack lots of basics. again, thanks!

Comment: but like, can you educate me a bit about the with? It would help for future coding I'm going to make. thank you again!

Comment: Yes. Stop using `with`. It can cause hard-to-find bugs. It's much better to remove it and just type the extra characters than it is to waste hours trying to solve a problem caused by unexpected results of a with statement.

Comment: To expand on @Ken's comment: `with` was very useful in old Pascal, where it could be used to make certain pieces of code more efficient. But that was in the days of simple, non-optimizing compilers and when Pascal did not have any object oriented extensions. These days, especially because of OO with much more complex scopes, `with` can become a big problem and should be avoided.

Comment: @mizkyd you used `with` in the code you posted. You did so without knowing what it does?

Comment: @mizkyd: [Why should I not use "with" in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71419/62576)