# Multidimensionnal array in Php and Mysql Insert

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a script which help me to get informations about new books from a website. I have 8 informations (title, author, editor...) to insert, and on each page, there is ten or less books to scan.

The final step is the query, but I have some problems to understand multidimensionnal array.

My prepare syntax :

```
$req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO listing(id, Ref, Nom, Auteur, Editeur, Prix, EAN, Small_desc, Dispo) VALUES(\'\', :Ref, :Nom, :Auteur, :Editeur, :Prix, :EAN, :Small_desc, :Dispo)');
```

And the query... I've made the test with the first line. That's works ! But I Wish to insert all the results.

```
$req->execute(array('Ref'=>$sortie4[1][0], 'Nom'=>$sortie[1][0], 'Auteur'=>$sortie2[1][0], 'Editeur'=>$sortie3[1][0], 'Prix'=>$sortie6[1][0], 'EAN'=>$sortie5[1][0], 'Small_desc'=>$sortie7[1][0], 'Dispo'=>$sortie8[1][0]));
```

I've found some examples about multidimensionnal array, but I don't understand how I could use them.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You should use Transactions and execute the statement for each item in your array. Check out e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples).

Comment: Is the second row in `[2][0]` or `[1][1]`?

Comment: You appear to have multiple multi dimensional arrays, but from your description you seem to be saying all the details are stored in a single multi dimensional array.

Comment: The second row is [1][1] the third [1][2].. and for each variable "sortie".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
$req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO listing(id, Ref, Nom, Auteur, Editeur, Prix, EAN, Small_desc, Dispo) VALUES(\'\', :Ref, :Nom, :Auteur, :Editeur, :Prix, :EAN, :Small_desc, :Dispo)');

foreach($sortie4[1] as $key => $value)
{
    $req->execute(array(':Ref'=>$sortie4[1][$key], ':Nom'=>$sortie[1][$key], ':Auteur'=>$sortie2[1][$key], ':Editeur'=>$sortie3[1][$key], ':Prix'=>$sortie6[1][$key], ':EAN'=>$sortie5[1][$key], ':Small_desc'=>$sortie7[1][$key], ':Dispo'=>$sortie8[1][$key]));
}
```

Changes are:

- Added foreach so that the statement is prepared once, then `execute()` looped for each row to insert. By capturing the key, you can access the relevent element in your other arrays.
- Your parameter names didn't have `:` prefix in the execute call, I added those.

Side note: your array isn't in the most ideal structure. You have several multidimensional arrays, one for each column. Instead you should only need one for example:

```
$arr = array(
    array('Ref' => '...', 'id' => '...', 'Nom' => '...'),
    array('Ref' => '...', 'id' => '...', 'Nom' => '...'),
    array('Ref' => '...', 'id' => '...', 'Nom' => '...'),
    array('Ref' => '...', 'id' => '...', 'Nom' => '...')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read **[THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)** to learn more about arrays.

Comment: That's the first page I have try to understand. But, I didn't see an example which can help me.

Comment: I don't think so. Try this in your code: `$array = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");
var_dump($array);`

If you are beginner`try to understand the simpler examples and then you can move on little complicating examples. I think this link which I post has what you need.

Comment: Also you can always use var_dump() to see what your array looks like. var_dump() is great function for code debugging.