# MySQL query doesn't work while using wpdb->prepare

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, oop

I need to insert into two tables at the same time so I'm using BEGIN and COMMIT in the query using `$wpdb->query()` and `$wpdb->prepare()` but unfortunately it doesn't work

Testing by [ `die( $wpdb->last_error );` ],

Generates [ *`WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME ( name ) VALUES ( 'xxxxxx' ); at line 2]`* ]

P.S. I copied the printed query and paste it in mySQL Query window and IT WORKS!!!

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
       "BEGIN;
       INSERT INTO {$tbl_accounts} ( name ) 
           VALUES ( %s );
       SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @last_seller_id;
       INSERT INTO {$tbl_apps} ( seller_id, slug, name, token ) 
           VALUES ( @last_seller_id, %s, %s, %s );
       COMMIT;",
       $seller_name,
       $app_name_sanitized, 
       $app_name, 
       $token_key ) 
);
```

Comment: Does WP allow multiple queries?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153986/how-to-use-mysql-transaction-in-wordpress

Comment: So how to return the last inserted id using this method? Since $wpdb->query() return the number of row affected

Comment: Output the query as plain text, with the data objects, copy it and insert it into HeidiSQL or whatever you're using. Usually it will be more in depth within Heidi.