# php POST on success from form to two different tables at the same time

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I am getting the values from a form individually and then posting them to the db on submission. The code I have below works fine

```php
$output['success'] = $wpdb->insert('my_Tablename', array(
    'one' => $one, 
    'two' => $two, 
    'three' => $three, 
    'four' => $four, 
    'five' => $five
));
```

but what if I want to post some fields to a supplemental table at the same time? How would I do that? Its not `$output2` as I tried that, and I cant add a comma between the $wpbd inserts, so what would the solution be? I want to add:

```php
$output['success'] = $wpdb->insert('my_Tablename_two', array( 
    'one' => $one, 
    'two' => $two, 
    'three' => $three, 
    'four' => $four, 
    'five' => $five
));
```

Comment: You could try recording the insert counts in separate variables, eg `$res1 = $wpdb->insert(...); $res2 = $wpdb->insert(...)` and then set the output to the combined total, ie `$output["success"] = $res1 + $res2;`. Of course, you probably want to perform these two inserts in a [transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153986/how-to-use-mysql-transaction-in-wordpress)

Comment: brilliant that makes good sense, thank you