# POST issue with submitting into 2 different database

Tags: php

i'm new to PHP development

i face some issue when i try to submit a data to the database
here is my code which i'm trying to insert into a db name topic and image.

```
$user = '1';
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $msg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['msg']);
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $img= "";
    $iname = $_FILES['file_1']['name'];
    $temp4 = $_FILES['file_1']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$iname);
    $path = "upload/".$iname;

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO topic (UserID, Title, MsgBody, DateTime)     VALUES('".$user."', '".$title."', '".$msg."', '".$date."')");
    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO image (TopicID, ImgPath)    VALUES('".mysql_insert_id()."', '".$path."')");

   }
   else 
   {
    echo "error";
   }
```

Comment: What issue do you face? Do you get an error? No data inserted? The wrong data? Some of the right data?

Comment: also you should really be using mysqli not mysql

Comment: [Why you shouldn't use mysql_* functions in PHP.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: no data inserted. i tried insert data by $title='test'; $msg='test';$path='/upload/1.jpeg'; the query works

Comment: could you please add the error , and also the tables schema .

Comment: @ErvinLew - there's no error checking in your code, at all. If your calls to `move_uploaded_file()` or `mysql_query()` don't work, you'll never know. You need to be checking what the return value of those functions are, and dealing with it as required. If your database queries are failing, then look in `mysql_error()`, and there'll be an error message from the database telling you what the issue is.

Comment: @andrewsi - as i meantion i'm new to this. i did add   <blink>
       $dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "mdb_kl237";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " .mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " .mysql_error());
    </blink>

Comment: @ErvinLew - you can add `or die(mysql_error())` after each of your calls to `mysql_query()`, too. You can add it as often as you need to - it's useful to add it whenever you're running queries.

Answer (score 0):

use transaction in this case where you need to do more tha 1 query.the link is given below [Transaction from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your code seem's to be fine **except** `mysql_insert_id` function. Depending on what PHP version you use, it is **deprecated** since PHP 5.5.0. See the **[documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)**.

Comment: the insertion work fine i try to run without the form.the data can be insert into the database