# Add auto incremented values to another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 tables:

```
1)'table'
    'id' - int autoincremented
    'name' - string

2) 'table2'
     'id' - int
     'info' - string
```

Lets, say the last row in `table` has `id`=20

After I insert 5 empty rows to `table`, last row has `id`=25

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`name`)
VALUES ((""),(""),(""),(""),(""))
```

1) First thing I need is to add 5 rows with same `id`-s and empty `info`-s to `table2`, right after they were added to `table`. Something like that:

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`,`info`)
VALUES ((21,""),(22,""),(23,""),(24,""),(25,""))
```

Can I do it using one statement?

2) Second thing I need is to extract these values to a PHP variable, like array or string (21,22,23,24,25), so that it could be used for further actions. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

1- you cant insert in two tables with one statment. you need two statments.

2- and if you using Mysqli or pdo you already have the option to bind parameters to variables.

edit>

```
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id); ---------> here you will get $id as variable of those ids
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Mysqli. What is the best way to gather information about inserted ids?

Comment: this is basic mysqli , look my edit on how to get the variable of ids

Answer (score 1):

1. Not in one statement, but in one block of statements that can be
   encapsulated in an atomic operation. You can make the insert
   statements dependent on one another by placing them into a single
   transaction.

   More information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html
2. The solution to your second problem will likely involve placing that
       transaction, along with some logic to return the extracted values to
       your application code, into a stored routine.

   More information:
       http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please provide an example of the transanction, basing on simple information provided in the question?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do any better than the official MySQL guide. You can find a thorough set of examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples