# Apply commit and rollback function for updating table in loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array which comprises many table and and their contents value for updating, I use foreach loop to get one by one a table and their updating record, then call a function which update the table

Code:

```
foreach($tables as $key=>$value) {
    function inset_data_into_table(take_table_name , table_field_and_value);
}
```

For example: If there are three table in array then three loops would be run, if two loops 
executed successfully but in third loop if there is an error come, then I want to rollback previous two loops inserted data. How it is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP + MySQL transactions examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)

Comment: No this is differenct case, Here we are calling function in loop. Please read the question once again carefully.

Comment: @SajidAliKhan But if function or not: The idea is the same ...