# Insert into two related tables

Tags: php, mysql

```
tbl_account
username | password | status

tbl_data
username | name | address | phone
```

how can i insert data into both tables with php? 
I tried with query

```
INSERT INTO tbl_account(username, password, status)
OUTPUT INSERTED.'bobo', 'Bobo Ali','Markt St. 26', '0979877'
INTO tbl_data(username, name, address, phone)
VALUES  ('bobo','bobo123','manager');
```

but it doesn't work at all. The process is success but the table is remain empty.

Comment: Is writing 2 queries not an option?

Comment: yes it's insert data into both tables

Answer (score 2):

You will need seperate queries for inserting the same data into multiple tables.

If you are having trouble with that, the process is simple:

1. Use the query to insert the data into the first table
2. Free the last result using mysqli_free_result() (or mysql_free_result() if you are using the MySQL API.
3. Reuse the same query you used in step 1. to insert the data into the second table

Code:

```
<?php

INSERT INTO tbl_account(username, password, status)
VALUES ('bobo', 'Bobo Ali','Markt St. 26', '0979877');

// Free the result here

INSERT INTO tbl_data(username, name, address, phone)
VALUES  ('bobo','bobo123','manager');

// Free the result again, so you can use the query again if needed

?>
```

Comment: If it's important that there are booth or neither entries in database (it seems like it is), then you should also have consider to use transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Use transactions. Alter your database like in the example and make userid primary key (auto increment)

```
tbl_account
userid | username | password | status

tbl_data
userid | username | name | address | phone

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO tbl_account(username, password, status)
  VALUES ('bobo','bobo123','manager');
INSERT INTO  tbl_data(username, name, address, phone)
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'bobo', 'Bobo Ali','Markt St. 26', '0979877');
COMMIT;
```

Check also this example if you want an example of php-MySQL(transaction) implementation.
[PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)

Comment: i have 3 different tbl_data, so like tbl_dataManager, tbl_dataAdmin, and tbl_dataCust and 1 tbl_account, can i use 'userid'?

Comment: yes you can, with an if statement regarding user's account-type (e.g. manager->1, admin->99, cust->2), so if user is admin you insert to dataAdmin, if user is Customer you insert to dataCust, and so on... of course this means that there is a field in tbl_account regarding account type

Answer (score 0):

you can only do with 2 seperate queries

```
INSERT INTO tbl_account(username, password, status)
 VALUES ('bobo', 'Bobo Ali','Markt St. 26', '0979877)'

Insert INTO tbl_data(username, name, address, phone)
VALUES  ('bobo','bobo123','manager');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to have two separate queries.
But the answers are a little bit misleading because the table tbl_account has only three columns whereas the provided code inserts values for four columns.

So it should be:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_account(username, password, status)
VALUES  ('bobo','bobo123','manager');

INSERT INTO tbl_data(username, name, address, phone)
VALUES ('bobo', 'Bobo Ali','Markt St. 26', '0979877');
```

Or you can write a procedure which these two inserts does.