# PHP How to use a Insert Query and a Delete Query in Conjunction

Tags: php, mysql

I searched a great deal for a solution to this problem, however i have had no luck in finding an answer, i am trying to archive a row from one table to another and then delete the row from the original table. I have the code set up how i think it should be but it only moves the record it does not delete it from the Original table.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'brokensky', 'password');
mysql_select_db('isad235database');

$select = filter_var($_POST['selectlist'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$query = "INSERT INTO `serversarchive` (`Server_ID`,`Server_name` , `Location` , `MAC_Address` , `Port_Number` , `IP_Address`, `Operating_System`, `Administrator`, `Contact_Number`, `Email` , `Second_Contact`, `Second_Contact_Number`, `Comments`)
SELECT * FROM `servers`
WHERE `Server_ID` = '$select'; DELETE FROM server WHERE Server_ID = = '$select'";
```

As i have looked around for several hours with no decent answer to this, i think this could be useful to others also.

Comment: you cant use multiple queries in one mysql_query() function call

Comment: you can't even use `mysql_query`)))

Comment: `= =` will also give you an error.

Comment: possible duplicate > [question 2708237](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the steps in sequence.  If they need to happen as an atomic unit, use a transaction.

See also: [PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)

Comment: Why can't he use multi query, supported by `mysqlnd` for example?

Comment: @DanFromGermany `mysqlnd` is not well supported on budget-oriented hosts.  Best to stick to the basics.  Anyway, I'm not familiar with it -- perhaps you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute sequentially.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `serversarchive` (`Server_ID`,`Server_name` , `Location` , `MAC_Address` , `Port_Number` , `IP_Address`, `Operating_System`, `Administrator`, `Contact_Number`, `Email` , `Second_Contact`, `Second_Contact_Number`, `Comments`)
SELECT * FROM `servers`
WHERE `Server_ID` = '$select'"; 

//execute first  

$query2 = "DELETE FROM server WHERE Server_ID = '$select'"; // == should be single =

//now execute this one.
```

Comment: This still does not work only the move is done the deletion of the record does not happen.

Comment: simple mistake...you are using double equals..`(= = )` ..it should be single =. corrected.