# How do you obtain the result of a particular query in a SQL transaction using PHP PDO function fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have a SQL transaction similar to the one below. I am unable to obtain the result of the 3rd query in the transaction using PHP function *PDO::fetch()*

```
$database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
$sql = "BEGIN;
        DELETE FROM users WHERE ID = 4;
        UPDATE audit SET nousers= nousers - 1 WHERE ID = 4;
        SELECT nousers FROM audit WHERE ID = 4;
        COMMIT;";
$query = $database->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
```

How do I use *$query->fetch()* to obtain the result of the 3rd query in the transaction?

Comment: Please check the link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples

Comment: @anantkumarsingh the link does not give an answer regarding obtaining the result of a transaction query using PDO::fetch(). I am not currently using mysql_* functions cause they are deprecated. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have five queries in your transaction, counting `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

Call `prepare()` and `execute()` five times, one for each of the queries. For your `SELECT` query, retrieve and examine the result set.

There's no need to put all queries of a transaction into a single `prepare` / `execute` cycle. The whole point of the transaction is to allow you to run multiple queries so they look like one unitary operation to other clients of the database server.