# Transaction: commit() vs rollBack()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have some queries at one script and I want to execute either all of them or none of them ..! I've searched about that and I figured out I have to use *transaction*.

Actually I want to use [PDO::beginTransaction](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php). Now there is two approaches.

- [rollback()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php) function
- [commit()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) function

So what's the difference between them? Both of them seems identical to me, So when should I use which one?

```
<?php

$dbh->beginTransaction();

$sth1 = $dbh->exec("DROP TABLE fruit");
$sth2 = $dbh->exec("UPDATE dessert SET name = 'hamburger'");
$sth3 = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO names(id, name) VALUES (NULL, 'peter')");

// which one?
$dbh->commit();
// or
$dbh->rollBack();
// ??

/* Database connection is now back in autocommit mode */
?>
```

Comment: Imagine rollBack is the cancel button and commit is the save button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both of them seems identical to me

That's wrong. Transaction by definition is `Atomic` in nature means either it will happen and succeed executing all commands in the group or none at all. If it's successful and you want to persist the change then `COMMIT` else if any of the statement in the group fails then `ROLLBACK` to get back to pristine state.

So in your case, you would want to have all the below statement execute successfully and if that then `COMMIT` to persist the change but if any of the statement fails for any so called reason then it may end up giving a undesired result which you don't want to persist and so `ROLLBACK` and get back to previous consistent state.

```
$sth1 = $dbh->exec("DROP TABLE fruit");
$sth2 = $dbh->exec("UPDATE dessert SET name = 'hamburger'");
$sth3 = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO names(id, name) VALUES (NULL, 'peter')");
```

Read about [Transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) and also see this another post [PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)

Comment: What do you mean *"If it's successful and you want to persist the change"*? Still I don't know what's the difference ..

Comment: ok first of all please tell me should I use both of them in my script of one of them?

Comment: @Shafizadeh, both of them, perform the transaction ... catch error and if any error then rollback else commit. Try reading about transaction basics to have better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You use commit to perform the transaction, and rollback is the opposite, you use rollback when you want to keep all unchanged (for example if you have detected some error during some step of the transaction).