# PHP/MySQL Handling Multi-step Insert Failure

Tags: php, mysql

During my site's signup process three inserts in separate tables occur to setup a new account:

1. INSERT INTO User
2. INSERT INTO Profile
3. INSERT INTO ProfileSetup

Currently, if a failure occurs at any point in the process, I kill the program and notify the user that an error has occurred. If a failure occurs on step 3 for whatever reason, technically the user account and profile are live and the user could log in, likely resulting in major problems. Not a good first impression.

I'm wondering what the best way to handle this is? If step 3 fails should I go back and delete the records created in step 1 and 2?

Comment: use transactions

Comment: I think Stored Proceduer will Fullfill you requirement. It will return error if any one of insert will failed and no need to revert your changes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples

Comment: Plain PDO example for transactions: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php. If you use a framework, check its docs for transactions.

Answer (score 0):

> If a failure occurs on step 3 for whatever reason ...

Ideally *all* possible reasons should be sussed out and built in to the design so that you are able to validate the data *before* any thing is touched in the database.

Here's is an example of a validation method as part of account creation in Opencart (line 223):

https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/account/register.php

As you can see all of the basic requirements are check before the database method in the model is called.

If you implement something like this, the only time I think your query could still fail would be a database crash or some other issue with the operating system.  In my experience this is extremely rare unless you have more serious underlying issues with your setup.  In that case, I think the comment above about using transactions is good advice.

Comment: True, but still the query could fail after a successful validation, for whatever reason.

Comment: What does *"for whatever reason"* mean?  What reason?  That's the point of a validation method.  That said, I agree with the comment above about transactions.  That's a great additional step, but 99.9% of the failures will be caught by a validation method

Comment: For whatever reason, as in _not data related_, the query could still fail. That's why I said _after successful validation_ :). I agree with you that proper validation will solve a lot and that it's a must-have, but you might still get a failed query.

Comment: There is a ton of data validation for both front and backend in place, so the issues should not be data related. It seems like transactions are the way to go so that I can roll everything back. The "for whatever reason" comment was a catch all for the unknown. For example an insert failing due to a dup entry.

Comment: @Robert - yes I agree.  I've revised my answer a bit.

Comment: @Runicode Well... `For example an insert failing due to a dup entry` is something you can validate :)

Comment: @Runicode - A duplicate entry is *always* something that should be part of your php validation.  If you notice line 236 of the example I gave that scenario is checked.

Comment: You're both correct it can be checked as part of my php validation, but it's also another query to execute. So I guess it's a trade off.  The profile table alone can have 10s of millions of records. Seems like it's faster to let a failure occur in the transaction on insert where a unique index is present than run the expensive select statement. Or am I off on this?

Comment: The select statement to check for duplicate entry shouldn't be expensive if an index is used.  In my opinion, relying on a a transaction failure for validation deprives you of the opportunity to return a useful message to the user about why the failure happened.

Comment: I want to say something important here based on real world experience - yes you should use ***both***.  But I've been a sysadmin for some rather large, high traffic  production ecommerce sites running older software that didn't use transactions and I've never once seen a series of queries fail for any reason other than a bug in the validation code or a server crash (extremely rare).  I understand it's theoretically possible and that's why transactions exist, but good php validation is really all you need to cover most issues.