# Mysql Query issue. Grant Usage * . * to user

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$user = substr(md5(rand()),0,16);
$pass = substr(md5(rand()),0,20);
$query = "CREATE USER '{$user}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{$pass}'; 
GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO '{$user}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{$pass}' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0; 
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `{$user}`; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `{$user}` . * TO '{$user}'@'%';";
mysql_connect("***.****.info", "***", "****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '78eb50407b017587'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY
>   '4fa70f7cc25ccf9dc9dd' at line 1.

Anyone know what's going on here

**Update** I removed identified by and it did nothing. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) doesn't support multiple query. Do the query one by one.

```
mysql_connect("***.****.info", "***", "****") or die(mysql_error());
$query1 = "CREATE USER '{$user}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{$pass}';";
$query2 = "GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO '{$user}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{$pass}' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;";
$query3 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `{$user}`;";
$query4 = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `{$user}` . * TO '{$user}'@'%';";
mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($query4) or die(mysql_error());
```

But, given the structure of your query, I would suggest you to do a transactions query. You can read more about it, here:

- [PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)
- [PHP & mySQL: Simple code to implement Transaction - Commit & Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133125/php-mysql-simple-code-to-implement-transaction-commit-rollback)

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer to such a stupid question! I love this site, and all the great members on it. I wish I could give people like you more than just an upvote and accept.